# How can I add more objects of a class to a vector without doing dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
class AClass
{
    // ...
}
```

~

```
class AnotherClass
{
    public:
        // ...
        void AMethod()
        {
            // ...
            AClass * ac = new AClass(); // Dynamic memory allocation here
            m_Objects.push_back(ac);
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    private:
        // ...
        std::vector<AClass *> m_Objects;
        // ...
}
```

I want to add new objects of `AClass` to the vector `m_Objects`.
Is there any other way of doing this without doing dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: Why not store `AClass` objects in the vector instead of pointers to `AClass` objects?  (Yes, there is still dynamic allocation for the underlying storage of the `vector`, but not for the individual elements.)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to do dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @Sanjit: Because it is not something desirable very much. It may cause memory leakage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things causing dynamic memory allocations here:

1. `vector::push_back`
2. `new AClass()`

Here is one idea how to reduce dynamic memory allocations.

First step is to call `m_Objects.reserve(N);` in the `AnotherClass` constructor, where `N` is the maximum number of `AClass` objects you want to keep at any given time. This reserves enough memory to remove the need for dynamic allocations by `vector::push_back`.

Second step is to make `m_Objects` contain objects instead of pointers, i.e. make it type `std::vector<AClass>` instead of `std::vector<AClass*>`. This allows you to skip `new` and directly create the new object by growing the container:

```
m_Objects.resize(m_Objects.size() + 1);
```

Now, there will be no dynamic allocation when adding a new object.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "can I create new objects at runtime without doing dynamic allocation?" then the answer is no.  That's what dynamic allocation is.

If you want to create some before they're immediately needed by creating them in bulk ahead of time, then that's plausible.  Simply allocate a large number and then pull them out of an array or vector as needed.

Comment: @Keith Irwin: I want to create at run-time.

Comment: @hkBattousai: That's the definition of dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Tomalak: Dynamic allocation usually means allocating memory from the heap. Memory allocation and object instantiation are two separate things (even if they usually go together). Just look up placement new.

Comment: @kotlinski: You're right about that. I was simplifying. As for "the heap", _no_. Heap and stack are outmoded, confusing and inaccurate terms for storage duration. C++ does not specify where these objects must be stored, and nowadays it's not necessarily the case that either is "the stack" or "the heap". Be accurate: objects with automatic storage duration are automatically destroyed when the block in which they are created exits; objects with dynamic storage duration are created with a new-expression, and their lifetime lasts until they are destroyed using a delete-expression.

Comment: @Tomalak: "The heap" means a large pool of memory it is possible to allocate from. "The stack" means the thread stack. How exactly is it inaccurate?

Comment: @kotlinski: Storage locations are completely unmandated by the standard. An implementation is free to put automatic storage duration objects in an abacus if it likes. And the term "heap" is a very specific memory structure, not always used these days for the _free store_, where your dynamic storage duration objects live.

Comment: @Tomalak: You are right - "heap" as in data structure and "heap" as in free store are unrelated - but it has been accepted terms since at least the 60s. You will find this in research and academic papers as well.

Comment: @kotlinski: I am well aware of that. That means neither that the term is correct nor that I must agree with it.

Answer (score 1):

Not so long as `m_Objects` is a `vector` of *pointers*, unless you were to store a pointer to an automatic (stack) variable.  But that, undoubtedly, would be a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways to allocate objects at runtime: dynamically on the heap, and on the call stack.

It is possible to instantiate multiple objects that are local (auto) variables within a function block by calling the function recursively, and adding these stack objects to your vector. But I'm pretty sure that's not what you really want.

That means that the only other way is to use `new` to dynamically create the new objects.

Comment: Heap and stack are outmoded, confusing and inaccurate terms for storage duration. C++ does not specify where these objects must be stored, and nowadays it's not necessarily the case that either is "the stack" or "the heap". Be accurate: objects with automatic storage duration are automatically destroyed when the block in which they are created exits; objects with dynamic storage duration are created with a new-expression. Their lifetime lasts until they are destroyed using a delete-expression.